# Web table with objects in the table cells

Tags: hp-uft

I have web table and it has check box and web link objects in the different cells. I need to compare part of text in the link in one cell and check the corresponding check box in another cell. Can anyone help with the code please?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. very first thing you can do is to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Look at the `ChildItem` method of the `WebTable` object in UFT Help.  That will give you an example to work from.  If you are still having trouble once you have written some code, come back, post the code and we can help you fix it.

Comment: Get the columns and rows count -> run a loop on a column having link text -> get the row number that has the desired text -> handle the checkbox in corresponding row using row number.